# Backup directory error in uninstallation redundant Anaconda from Macintosh HD

Tags: python, anaconda

I accidentally installed Anaconda twice, in Macintosh HD (/anaconda2 << I changed the folder name here) and in home path (Users/myname/anaconda). I wanted to uninstall Anaconda2 in Macintosh and remain another one to use. Using andromeda-clean for complete uninstallation, I got error due to backup directory. How should I do?

```
h22% pwd
>/anaconda2
h22% anaconda-clean --yes
>Backup directory: /Users/myname/.anaconda_backup/2017-03-15T205621
>Error: Unable to move /Users/myname/.continuum
h22% anaconda-clean      
>Delete .continuum? (y/n): y
>Backup directory: /Users/myname/.anaconda_backup/2017-03-15T205634
>Error: Unable to move /Users/myname/.continuum
```

This is my path in zsh.

```
h22% nano ~/.zshrc
># recommended by brew doctor
>export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
>eval "$(rbenv init - --no-rehash)"

>PATH="$PATH:$HOME/anaconda/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
```

Here is python 2.7.13 on OS X E Capitan 10.11.6